# In glycolysis, what is the source of the electron that makes NAD+ into NADH instead of NADH+?

Tags: metabolism, cellular-respiration, bioenergetics, glucose

I looked at the formula for the glycolysis reaction. The overall reaction seems balanced, however, I don't see anything on the left hand side of the equation that would provides the electron to convert NAD+ to NADH. Where does that electron come from?

Comment: This question would be much better if you included the reaction (then it would be considered your research) in the body of your question, the whole 'equation', including the enzyme(s). One reaction in detail would be sufficient. Otherwise, this reads like a homework question, even though it may not be.

Comment: If it were a proton transfer, it would be NADH2+ (You already had a plus charge on the NAD+ cation). What is another of a molecule picking up a hydrogen and an electron in exactly the same step?

Comment: @Hal I agree with anongoodnurse above - question as stated is vague... are you trying to balance the NAD+ and NADH?

Comment: @VanceLAlbaugh The question isn't vague, it is just that Hal is forgetting that there are ways other than proton transfer for a molecule to pick up a hydrogen.